# bash select loop doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to learn bash. In some tutorial, I found select loop. But it doesn't work on either my MAC OS or Linux. My code is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
names="Kyle Cartman Stan Quit"
PS3="Select character: "
select name in $names
    do
    echo "name="$name
done
```

I use ./test.sh to call this program and the result it like this:

```
1) Kyle
2) Cartman
3) Stan
4) Quit
Select character: Kyle
name=
Select character: Stan
name=
Select character:
```

It seems that it can not detect my input.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

The code is fine; its usage is wrong: The allowed entries are `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`, not `Kyle`, `Cartman`, `Stan`, or `Quit`. (If the user had to type the whole name, what's the point of putting numbers by them?)

The empty string tells you that the user entered something invalid. Observe, by contrast:

```
1) Kyle
2) Cartman
3) Stan
4) Quit
Select character: 1
name=Kyle
Select character: 3
name=Stan
```

---

By the way -- it should be:

```
# SAFE: quotes everything
echo "name=$name"
```

...or...

```
# SAFE: Quotes only the expansion
echo name="$name"
```

...not...

```
# BUGGY: Runs expansion unquoted; can remove characters in IFS, expand globs, etc
echo "name="$name
```

See [When Should You Quote?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F) on the Wooledge wiki, or make a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/, which will find issues of this nature.

Comment: Thank you for your such a fast and thorough explanation. Now I get it work.

Comment: @KyleZeng, ...to explain what artM means -- clicking a checkbox next to an answer that solved your problem will mark your question as resolved.